# 2 divs same height with border-bottom

Tags: html, css

2 divs have same height. I tried all hacks (also with jquery) but the

```
padding-bottom: 1000px;
margin-bottom: -1000px;
```

hack works best. The right column need a bottom border but its not showing, because margin-bottom: -1000px.

Is there any solution? I made a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s92rzcsz/

Comment: For a more robust solution that works cross-browser (IE8+) try this plugin http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/ it'll allow you to style the divs however you please

Comment: check this. Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/s92rzcsz/7/

Comment: This is interesting. I've never seen aligning done this way before. A lot of the designs I work with involve inline blocks with equal heights but it's always tricky. I spent some time creating a js helper ([AlignJs][1]) but it looks like a js solution already exists @DeanElliott .. damn!


  [1]: https://github.com/jacksonv1lle/AlignJS

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to worry about IE < 8 then you could use use display:table-cell and just give the two cells contents and apply a normal border to the div-bottom of div1

```
div1, div2 {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: thank you. I know the table solution but I cant use it for some reason (bootstrap) etc.

Comment: bootstrap places no restrictions on being able to use a display:table, display:table-row, display:cell anywhere in you code.  but there a loads of worked examples on css-tricks such as http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/5-columns-of-equal-height-super-simple-two-column-layout/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        Some content!<br/>
        Some content!<br/>
        Some content!<br/>
        Some content!<br/>
        Some content!<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="column blackborder">Something</div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    display: table;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.column {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
.blackborder{
border-bottom:2px solid #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s92rzcsz/5/

you can achieve this using a table

Answer (score -1):

i have a possible answer if is always the same style. in the first column div create a span inside it, to put the border,

the difficult part is in the second column, you have to write some `<br>` as lines you need.

```
<div class="column">
something
    <div class="test"></div>    
</div>

.test{
border-bottom:2px solid #000;    
}
```

here the example
https://jsfiddle.net/s92rzcsz/6/